# DisplayPort over USB Type-C not working

Tags: usb, display, displayport

I have a 
**Philips BDM4037UW 4K screen** 
connected to my 
**Asus ROG GL552VW**
via 
**USB Type-C**
using a 
**Club3d USB Type-C -> DisplayPort Adapter**

However it does not work. The screen gives me a *"No input detected"* and my laptop says *"Try improving the USB connection. DisplayPort connection might not work. Try a different cable."*

Does this mean I can forget about displaying my laptop on a 4K screen @60hz?

How can I find out if my laptop supports the DisplayPort alt mode at all? Could it be the cable is not good?

Might it work with a USB Type-C -> HDMI 2.0 adapter?

Any other recommendations?

Comment: HDMI functionality over USB Type-C connector is strictly optional, and requires a lot of muxing and routing and control on manufacturer's side. Why would everyone assume that USB Type-C automatically implies HDMI functionality?

Comment: @AliChen DisplayPort*. That's because I'm a hardware n00b. I see a way to connect shit; I assume it works :D Learning the hard way.

Comment: What is wrong with the native HDMI port on your laptop? GTX960 should support HDMI 2.0 with 4k@60Hz...

Comment: @AliChen You are right. Unfortunately the HDMI port is 1.x (Correct me if I'm saying something stupid). Also it's wired to the Intel HD Graphics 530, if that makes any difference. Nevertheless I'm curently using it on that HDMI port. Picture quality is great, but there's a slight delay for mouse movements, and it's not 60Hz, which for development work is fine, but for gaming is just horrible.

Comment: Yes, if it is 530 only, then it can do only HDMI 1.4, and if (since) your laptop doesn't have DP routed, you are out of luck. Note though that your display has two HDMI ports, but they are different, only one of them can support HDMI 2.0.

Comment: @AliChen I'm aware of the different HDMI Ports yes :) Thanks for the help, I'll probably trade in my laptop for one with the right specs.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that ASUS ROG GL552VW does not support sending video over USB3.1 because the display port function is either not implemented or disabled.

Check this forum thread:

https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?82155-GL552VW-USB-TYPE-C-Question-and-Connecting-Additional-Monitor

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Guess I'll return it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have a few PCs in our office with the same problem. I found a workaround. Output from standard USB 3.0 to HDMI using an adapter.

You can also use a USB 3.1 Type C to USB 3.0 hub, too, and then plug in a USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter.

Under Windows, we found the J5Create adapters to work well, and under Linux we had to got for the slightly more expensive Unitek models.